# Custom navbar theme in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navbar, nav

So I am in the process of building a custom theme in wordpress. Using trial and error I have managed to figure out most of it however I am struggling when creating a custom navbar.

Essentially I am copying an existing website from a general PHP site to wordpress so the owner can modify it more freely and have a blog. They want it to be a carbon copy of their own site so I need to find a way to implement their navbar into wordpress so that they can also dynamically add pages to it through wordpress. I am predominantly a back end web developer so this is not my forte.

```
<nav class="header-submenu default-container" role="navigation">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="../contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
        <a href="../our-process">OUR PROCESS</a>
        <a href="../who-we-are">WHO WE ARE</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">testpage<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3 container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><h3>Cat 1</h3></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/1">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/2">2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><h3>Cat 2</h3></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/3">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/4">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/5">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/6">6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><h3>Cat 3</h3></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/7">7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.testsite.co.uk/testpage/8">8</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>

        <a class="signIn-button" href="http://testsite.co.uk/login.php">sign in</a>
        <a class="apply-btn" href="#apply-form">APPLY</a>
        <a class="call-btn" href="tel:00000000000">CALL US</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is my navbar in my header.php and I am seriously at a loss as to where to start to replicate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a menu:

> To add a custom navigation menu, the first thing you need to do is register your new navigation menu by adding this code to your theme’s functions.php file.

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Then you need to add it to your theme:

> You will need to add this code in your theme’s template file where you want to display your menu.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
?>
```

And add the CSS under `custom-menu-class`.

There's a lot more detail here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

The actually entries in the menu to different pages would be managed by the menu editing tool in the admin interface.

If you don't care about editing the menu, you could just add the menu code you've pasted directly into your theme.

Comment: My Navbar is appearing vertical rather than horizontal? Do you know a quick fix for that?

Comment: @KyleWardle you most likely need to add the appropriate CSS styles to it. See here for an example: http://css-snippets.com/simple-horizontal-navigation/